# Java Read cygwin paths as local paths

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, cygwin

I have created folder in cygwin `/data/sample/sample.txt`. Now from java program I want to read this path as if I am reading a Unix.

```
File f = new File("/data/sample/sample.txt")
```

But the above code will give error Path not found. How can I make it work?

Comment: java is NOT cygwin aware , so you need to use Windows path

Comment: That is exactly why I am asking this? How to make this possible?

Comment: Is your problem that you want to be able to use Cygwin paths in a Java program for referring to files?

Comment: No I want to use cygwin path as local unix path in java program, without prefixing windows absolute path

Answer (score 0):

The cygwin `/data/sample/sample.txt` is not understood by the Java machine as it is a windows program. You need to pass it the equivalent Windows path.
`cygpath` can help you to translate:

```
$ cygpath -w /data/sample/sample.txt
C:\cygwin64\data\sample\sample.txt
```

so

```
File f = new File("C:\cygwin64\data\sample\sample.txt")
```

assuming `C:\cygwin64` is where your Cygwin installation is located

Comment: This is not what I am expecting. I want to access my file path as unix path only.

Comment: You can't as JAVA do NOT understand it.